# Cannot clone private bitbucket repo through ansible

Tags: git, bitbucket, ansible, ssh-agent

I have the following configurations in ansible.cfg

```
sudo_flags = -H -S -n
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes

- name: Fetch code from git repo
  git:  repo={{repo_url}}
        dest={{ proj_path }}
        version={{ repo_version }}
        accept_hostkey=yes
        force=true
```

Keep in mind that I also have same tasks that run as sudo before this one

The error message is:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '2401:1d80:1010::150' to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '2401:1d80:1010::150' to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: Did you try deleting the key on the host where you are cloning. Seems like there is a wrong key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts and ~/.ssh/authrozed_keys

Answer (score 2):

That error message indicates either that the key Ansible is using doesn't have permission to clone from that Bitbucket repo, or that Ansible isn't using the key it should be using. There's no clear indication from that message which of those problems it's having, so you'll have to dig a little to figure out what's going on.

---

First, test the key's permissions with `ssh -i /path/to/key git@bitbucket.org`.

If you get `Permission denied (publickey)` then the key isn't associated with any user or added as a deployment key to any repo. Add the public key to the user or repo that needs it.

If you get something like this -

```
logged in as some-username-here.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

then the key is associated with that user's account.

If you get something like this -

```
authenticated via a deploy key.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:
```

then the key is added as a deployment (i.e. read-only) key to those repos.

---

If the key's permissions are good, then either the ssh-agent isn't running or it doesn't know the key. Try updating your `ssh_args` to something like this:

```
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -i /path/to/key
```

That will force Ansible to connect using the specified key.